# Are questions purely about personal visa usage on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

So there's two questions I wanted to contrast here

1. [Why do Mauritius passport holders have such easy visa access to so many countries?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/27325/why-do-mauritius-passport-holders-have-such-easy-visa-access-to-so-many-countrie)
2. [If you have a SMOM passport are you able to legally enter the Netherlands?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/27330/if-you-have-a-smom-passport-are-you-able-to-legally-enter-the-netherlands)

#1 is a good Politics.SE question, asking why the visa policy has been changed the way it has.

#2 should, IMO, be off-topic. It's not about the politics of visa acceptance, it's about actually getting into a country. The question should be migrated to [Travel.SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/), where it is on-topic (and questions like that are frequently asked)

So is #2 on-topic?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I agree with your assessment.

The first question is on-topic, because it asks "***why*** are these the visa rules for X?" and specifically asks for the political reasons.

The second question is off-topic, because "***what*** are the visa rules for X?" isn't a political question. You don't need to know the political backgrounds to answer the question, just the local travel regulations. That's the area of expertise of Travel Stack Exchange. I migrated the question.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with your assessment and Philipp's: Travel is definitely the right place for that particular question and such questions should be off-topic here.

In regards to the more general question in the title, I would add to Philipp's answer the caveat that not all visa questions belong on Travel. Questions about visas for long-term immigration (i.e. moving to a different country, such as for work, college, etc.) rather than for short-term visits should be directed to [Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/) instead of Travel. These questions are generally considered off-topic at Travel.